# Looping through a CSV file and storing line value in a variable C#

Tags: c#, api, loops, csv

I want to cycle through a single columned CSV of emails and store them in a variable that can be used to make an API call.  So the first email in the CSV would be stored in a variable, the api call would be made, the response would be stored in database and then the second email would be called.  Any help on this would be much appreciated.  Some of the code I have left out as it contains my api key and information.

```
    private string CreateRequest(string queryString)
    {
        string UrlRequest = requestUrl + ReadEmail() + queryString;
        return UrlRequest;
    }

  private string[] ReadEmail()
   {
        new StreamReader("App_Data/list.csv");
         {
          foreach  (var email in Emails) {
           string line = email.ReadToEnd();
           string[] emails = line.Split(',');
           return Emails;
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. 
See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: A "single columned CSV" file isn't a CSV as there are no values to be separated by commas. However, you are splitting by a `','`, so does that man that you have a file with a single line with email addresses separated by commas?

Comment: It is just limited by a comma.  each comma breaks to new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your reading function first and then call your api for each value retrieved:

```
private static void YourApiCall(string email)
{
   //...
}

private static void RunApiWithEmailsFrom(string file)
{
    System.IO.File.ReadLines(file).ToList().ForEach(YourApiCall);
}
```